# Cannot obtain user by using filter with username and password

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-users

I am using the following code

```
email = validated_data["login"]
password = validated_data["password"]
user_obj = User.objects.filter(Q(email__exact=email) & Q(password__exact=password))
```

I changed the password from admin however no user is returned. However if I remove the password check then I get a user object back.The object that I get back if I remove the `Q(password__exact=password)` condition has _password field as None. This code has been working fine for a while but today it is not returning back the object. Am I missing something here ? I verified that I am receiving the correct username and password from the client.I also tried accessing the admin with that username and password (The account has staff status) and I was able to log in. So the password is correct but for some reason I cant obtain that user by filtering. ? What might I be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`password` isn't stored in plain text, but as a hash (and a little more). Get the user by username and check the password:

```
# assumes there can be only one
user = User.objects.get(email=email) 
# this checks the plaintext password against the stored hash 
correct = user.check_password(password)
```

BTW, you don't need `Q` objects for logical `AND`. `filter(email__exact=email, password__exact=password)` would suffice, even though it doesn't make much sense, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

it is because Django doesn't stores password as the simple text they are hashed, you cant perform a password__exact on that it will return none every time unless you are getting the same hash `password = validated_data["password"]` here

Comment: I could have sworn this was working before. How do I verify a user then. I cannot use authentication here as this code is being called from a Rest API ?

Comment: for that you can user.check_password as pointed by @schwobaseggl

Comment: for reference take a look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/